What prevented invertebrates from discovering flight a second time?
Vertebrates evolved powered flight three times in history, being pterosaurs, birds, and finally, bats.
Invertebrates were the first to evolve flight on the planet... but flying insects remained the only one, with all flying insects descending from a single common ancestor to a boot. This is while insects are famous for their extreme morphological plasticity and fast speciation tendency.
So the question is - what prevented invertebrates from discovering flight more than once, especially considering that bats prove that you can still successfully try to emerge into a niche already occupied by other species (birds, who themselves coexisted with pterosaurs for tens of millions of years) and that invertebrates have more anatomical plasticity compared to vertebrates?
This question is NOT about: How evolution works

Yes, it is. That is the correct question and answer to explain this. It's not possible to give another answer.
